# Android Wi-fi AP hotspot - without internet

Tags: android, wifi

There are lots of post on SO regarding setting up AP (Hotspot) on android mobile. However, in all these cases, the AP is a conduit to the outside internet world. In my case, I just want a server application running over a mobile setup as an AP.  And let all the client android mobiles connect to it, send their data and disconnect if they like. No internet connection is assumed (i.e, no gprs/3g etc).

My observations: If I setup a wifi AP (via settings -> tethering and portable hotspots) when it is also connected to GPRS, then another android phone can successfully connect to this AP and send the data to the application.  However, if I disable the GPRS, even though the client shows that it is connected to the AP, it can't seem to send any data. It seems that an external internet connection is a necessity for the AP mode to work.

Is this understanding correct? Or am I setting something wrong?

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246200/hotspot-dhcp-issues-without-mobile-data-dhcp4-request-timed-out

Answer (score 3):

I know that I am late to the party (more than 3 years late :) but I was searching for a solution to this problem and stumbled upon an easy workaround. I am using a Nexus 4 with Android 5.0.1 and I can easily configure my phone to use it as an Android Wi-fi AP hotspot - without internet. Just go to `Settings / Data Usage`  and disable "`Mobile data`" option under the Mobile tab. Then enable the WiFi hotspot option as usual.

I was trying to get this working in order to play with a VirtualBox machine from VulnHub.com that asked for a Bridged Connection when I was commuting to work (no Internet, but with my laptop and my mobile phone I was able to make it :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to connect my Mac with my Android phone over hotspot and my phone has mobile data turned off. Is there any app available that I can test interaction between mobile and PC over hotspot without internet ?

Comment: @ranganath111 I believe you were looking for the `ping` utility

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used the internet IPs in your code not the local IPs for communications,is'nt it?

Comment: No, I am using local ip. The AP has an IP of 192.168.43.1 and the client gets an ip of 192.168.43.75 (for example).  Basically I am just trying to figure out how to get two android devices to communicate with each other without rooting them.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

communicating of two android devices is possible with sockets, you are saying that if the client listen on specific port and the server open and connect to the for example 192.168.43.75 and the port that client are listening to, for example 1111 and try to send a sample data if the GPRS be disable the data wont be send?!

Comment: do you use any firewall on your phone? disable them and try again,
and which version of android do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same use case and was looking for the same info as you are. I checked that some of the WiFi-only tablets do not even have a HotSpot setting. Even the devices that do have it, if I remove the SIM card, I cannot enable the HotSpot (I get a message asking me to insert a SIM first).

It looks like our use case is not supported by Android. Rather, the HotSpot feature was not designed with our use-case in mind. I mean, why would an end-user want to use an Android phone or tablet in a HotSpot mode if it didn't also provide outside connectivity?

Comment: I have several devices (Nexus 5, Galaxy S4 Play edition) which with no SIM card perform this feature without trouble, so I doubt this is the concern, except perhaps from the manufacturers tampering with things they should have left alone.